# Lisitsin Gambit Traps

Tags: opening, gambits

I've started to play the Lisitsin Gambit (1.Nf3 f5 2.e4), and this opening works well for me. However, I have analysed my games and found I have neglected to take advantage of several traps. What are the main traps in this opening?

Comment: The hardest part about playing the Lisitsin Gambit is getting your opponents to play 1...f5. How do you manage that?

Comment: Wait for my opponent to play 1...f5!

Comment: Could you show us some of those games? There are many sacrifices on h7, but without further information it's hard to guess where you're making your mistakes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try for Zukertort Trap in the Lisitsin Gambit line.

After 1. Nf3 f5 2. e4

the trap-line is Ng5

then if the opponent sticks with his pawn on f5, and pushes d5, then, simply play d3, followed by exd3 and then play Bxd3, and notice that the king has serious weakness on one of its diagonals.

Now, if opponent replies with Nf6, then the best option is Nxh7. If black captures with Nxh7, then Bg6(check), Kd7 and then Qxd5 (mate).

You can also go for, Bxh7 instead of Nxh7, also its winning for you, after Nxh7, you play Qh5, Kd7; Nf7, Qe8, Qxd5 (mate) and if black captures the bishop with rook, then you take it with the Knight, then Nxh7, and Qh5, checking the queen and picking up the Knight.